# How can I use my PC (running on windows) as a bluetooth audio device for my android phone?

Tags: java, android, windows

Suppose I get a call at my android phone. What I want is this call to be routed to my bluetooth/wifi connected PC just like it is routed to any other android audio device.

Comment: This site is about programming problems. Not hardware setup issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have embedded Bluetooth hardware just use accompanying software and set your PC (after pairing) headset/speakers as a Hands-free device. That's it.
2. If you have BT USB-dongle try to install Bluesoleil software and do the same as above. It's simple but not very stable piece of s..oftware, so it may work or it may not. In this case you can try Broadcom WIDCOMM Bluetooth Driver 12.0.1.940 and again set that so you could use your PC headset as a Hands-free device.

I'm sorry I can't tell you exact steps because I don't have Bluetooth on my PC atm. But believe me it's very easy. It was some time ago but it was like half a minute to set things up.

Hope this will help.